# Is there a way to make a object available in the whole scope in react.js

Tags: reactjs, cookies

Is there a way to create an object and use it in the whole class in react. Not in state, because now i have a problem i need to initialize a object class (cookie) and i need to ref it from inside fetch method. In other words how to create the object and pass it to the state or make it usable in the whole class. I know i am missing some fundamentals but i post the question after i read tutorials, articles, questions and i didn't find a way to achieve this sorry if the questions seems to be very basic. I will provide some code to show you what i try to do. Btw if someone can show me some resources to read because i go into this problem not for the first time and i am missing something for example the task i want to achieve in java is easy you declare the variable at the start of the code and its done. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';

class Home extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const { cookies } = new Cookies();             <-- I want to pass this object into state.
        this.state = {
            veichles: [],
            filteredItems: [],
            user: {},
            query: '',
            password: '',
            welcome: '',
            welcomeMsg: '',
            token: '',
        };

    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({query: e.target.value})
    }

    handlePassword = e => {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value})
    }

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch(  `myresource/customer/auth/${this.state.query}/${this.state.password}`,
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    credentials: "same-origin"
                },
                credentials: "include",
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        user: result,
                        password: result                         <-- state
                    });
                    cookies.set('token', result, { path: '/' }); <-- i want to use it here or in the state above
                }
            )

        this.setState( { welcomeMsg: 'Hello, ' } );
    }

    render() {
        const { filteredItems } = this.state;
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12} >
                        <form className={style.form1}>
                             <input  content="Username" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                             <input type="password"  onChange={this.handlePassword} />
                             <button className={style.button}  onClick={this.onSubmit}>Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}> <Jumbotron {...this.state} /> </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}


export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `this.cookies = cookies` inside the constructor. Then you should be able to access `this.cookies` wherever the correct class `this` context is there. In your case, you can use it at the place where you're trying to access at the moment.

Comment: Its still unresolved variable i just try it. Actually you just made another variable refer to this and they are both with the same scope

Comment: Sorry i didn't use it with "this". It is working thank you a lot.